# Wix pre-processor rejecting class files with `$anon$` in them from a Scala application

Tags: java, scala, wix, windows-installer, jpackage

I'm trying to automate the build process of my Scala application for producing a `msi` installer.

When doing so, windows claims that certain files cannot be found. Here is the command that gets run

> [21:39:01.842] Running C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\candle.exe in C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage6105194214114584024\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull

and further down, i start seeing errors like this:

> C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage6105194214114584024\config\bundle.wxf(56) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage6105194214114584024\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\FileMenu$anon$2.class'.

> C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage6105194214114584024\config\bundle.wxf(71) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage6105194214114584024\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\dialog\ViewEventDialog$anon$10$anon$21$anonfun$lessinit$greater$1.class'.

> C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage6105194214114584024\config\bundle.wxf(81) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage6105194214114584024\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\SettingsMenu$anon$5.class'.

You can see more instances of this error in the build log here:

https://github.com/bitcoin-s/krystal-bull/runs/2697961906?check_suite_focus=true#step:8:11

My question is this:

What are the limitations in the windows file system or the program `candle.exe` that prevent the pre-processor from reading Scala files that include things like `$anon$`

Is there a valid syntax guide somewhere?

Will I need to manually rename all of these files?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised at the files it's looking for. When I create an app image the `app/classes` directory doesn't exist, and instead the `app` directory just contains the main jar. FWIW, I don't think the problem is the `$` in the file path. Java anonymous classes also use `$` in the name, and I can confirm creating an app image and then installer works here with a Java anonymous class.

Comment: Some things that come to mind is the Windows path length limit, but I think you're under that. Or inaccessibility of the Users directory, which you might be able to work around by setting an explicit temp directory using the jpackage `--temp` option